# PHP Warning when using rename() function "No data available"

Tags: php, laravel

When trying to use the PHP [rename](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) function with two valid paths (source and target), I get a warning with the following message:

> PHP Warning:  rename(/u01/www/user/project/image.jpg,/mnt/files/archive/image.jpg): No data available

The weird thing is that the file is actually copied (not moved, the original file still exists) but has 0 bytes and is corrupted.

Tried to Google this error, but can't find any information. Maybe a permissions issue?

Comment: Most probably permission/selinux issue. How about `var_dump(is_writable('/mnt/files/archive'));`

Comment: Likely a permissions issue, yes. If you're using Laravel, maybe consider using Laravel's filesystem Classes for this? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem, specifically https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#copying-moving-files, `Storage::copy()` or `Storage::move()` for renaming.

Comment: try actually copying and then deleting the original. It looks like the paths belong to different partitions/drives so `rename` wont work if that is the case

Comment: Ok, made some tests outside PHP scope, just using a terminal a the mv command, and getting the same error "No data available". Seems that the issue is related with the target path "/mnt/files/" (only happens when using this path as a target). This path is mounted as a volume with docker, not sure if could be related. The output of "is_writable" is true

Comment: There are some user comments in the PHP docs you linked to describing similar errors (error msg but mv actually works).

Answer (score 0):

Solution1

please check folder is writable or not.

```
is_writable('/mnt/files/archive/image.jpg').
```

Enable error reporting

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Now add some safety checks before:

```
$old_name='/u01/www/user/project/image.jpg';
$new_name='/mnt/files/archive/image.jpg';

if (file_exists($old_name) && 
    ((!file_exists($new_name)) || is_writable($new_name))) {
    rename($old_name, $new_name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution2

use copy() function instaed of rename.

```
$old_name='/u01/www/user/project/image.jpg';
$new_name='/mnt/files/archive/image.jpg';


if ( copy($old_name, $new_name) ) {
    echo "Copy success!";
}else{
echo "Copy failed.";
}
```